# EWS C# Attachment can't be updated

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to rename an Attachment in an EmailMessage object.

```
msg.Attachments.Where(c => c.Name == attachmentPdfFullNames[0]).FirstOrDefault().Name = "NEW NAME ATTACHMENT";
```

But it throw Exception **Attachment can't be updated**. I tried to copy and change name then remove and re-add attachment, but same :

```
Attachment a = msg.Attachments.Where(c => c.Name == attachmentPdfFullNames[0]).FirstOrDefault();
Attachment b = a;
b.Name = "NEW NAME ATTACHMENT";
msg.Attachments.Remove(a);
msg.Attachments.AddFileAttachment("./" + b.Name);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't rename an attachment in EWS (there is no operation to do this just Create and Delete). So you will need to remove the Attachment you want to rename and Re-Attach it.

With your code you need to Call update on the Message (which means the code performs the operation) after your remove and before you re-add the attachment then after you add the new attachment eg

```
 msg.Attachments.Remove(a);
 msg.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
 msg.Attachments.AddFileAttachment("./" + b.Name);
 msg.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
```

Comment: Thank you, i will test and i get back to you.